# Replacing values with wildcards (parsing text data)

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have rows which contains HTML tags. e.g.

```
<b>Abc</b> <strong>Bca</strong>
```

So I need to cut it out. As I suggest I need to find something like '%<%>%' and make a REPLACE to ''.

How can I do it? Interested for both solutions - MS SQL & Oracle also.

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: I'd Guess `Abc Bca`  since it says, i need to cut it out, it hopefully refering to the HTML tags. maybe `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(String,'<[^>]*>',' ') FROM T` for oracle don't know if it would work in SQL Server

Comment: we can't know that for sure though, he might have rows with normal data and rows with html tags and only wants the tags in his select in which case fieldname like "<%>%<%>" and I still don't know how to create that code tag around my code teach me @xQbert :D

Comment: [SQL Fiddle for oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2d17a/1/0)

Comment: xQbertб, REGEXP_REPLACE(String,'<[^>]*>',' ')  works perfectly, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming table is called `yourtable` and field is called `htmltag`.

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT  
SUBSTRING(substring(htmltag,charindex('>',htmltag)+1,250),0,CHARINDEX('<',
          substring(htmltag,charindex('>',htmltag)+1 ,250),0))
FROM yourtable
```

<kbd>[`SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/acdd6/8/0)</kbd>

In Oracle

```
SELECT regexp_replace(htmltag, '<[^>]+>', '') htmltag 
FROM yourtable
```

<kbd>[`SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/13bf3/5/0)</kbd>